# Map Clustering with Swift 2

Tags: swift2, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am looking for clustering markers in MapKit, so I found this library: [FBAnnotationClusteringSwift](https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift)
  that answers my needs.

But it is for swift 3. 
Can anyone find the same library for swift 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you found something else but here is your answer:

If you find something on github but it is in a newer version, you just have to search a previous version of this repo at the commits section.

[image]

This repo I think its working with swift 3 and swift 2 too (with pod install)
Maybe you faced a problem when you tried to insert his code from the usage.

Anyway [this is the link for swift 2.2](https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift/tree/d831c3cbb0a2cc28b52a1b8c1660a0443a964bda) if the pod installation is eventually for swift 3 use the manuall installation, just take the files and drop them to your project, and use the usage code to use the repo.

If you don't want swift 2.2 (so you have xcode < 7.3) I think this is [this is the link](https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift/tree/b4570f42bbb12ba23fa06474382cb3efa273f083)

Hope it helps you.